# Adding new custom mass order status action

Tags: grid, order-grid, massaction

I am using Magento 1.9.1 .

I am working on a new extension which is adding new custom mass status action here:

[image]

Here is my code:

/app/code/local/VivasIndustries/MassCustomStatusses/etc/config.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <VivasIndustries_MassCustomStatusses>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </VivasIndustries_MassCustomStatusses>
  </modules>
<global>
  <adminhtml>
    <events>
        <core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
            <observers>
                <masscustomstatusses_core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
                    <class>masscustomstatusses/observer</class>
                    <method>newMassAction1</method>
                </masscustomstatusses_core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
            </observers>
        </core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
    <blocks>
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <sales_order_grid>VivasIndustries_MassCustomStatusses_Block_Sales_Order_Grid</sales_order_grid>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
    </blocks> 
</global>
</config>
```

/app/code/local/VivasIndustries/MassCustomStatusses/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php:

```
<?php
class VivasIndustries_MassCustomStatusses_Block_Sales_Order_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid
{   
    protected function _prepareMassaction()
    {
        parent::_prepareMassaction();

        // Append new mass action option 
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem(
            'masscustomstatusses',
            array('label' => $this->__('New Mass 1'), 
                  'url'   => $this->getUrl('masscustomstatusses/controller/action') //this should be the url where there will be mass operation
            )
        );
    }
}
```

/app/code/local/VivasIndustries/MassCustomStatusses/Model/Observer.php:

```
<?php
class VivasIndustries_MassCustomStatusses_Model_Observer
{
    public function newMassAction1($observer)
    {
        $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();
        if(get_class($block) =='Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Massaction'
            && $block->getRequest()->getControllerName() == 'sales_order')
        {
            $block->addItem('masscustomstatusses', array(
                'label' => 'New Mass 1',
                'url' => Mage::app()->getStore()->getUrl('masscustomstatusses/controller/action'),
            ));
        }
    }
}
```

So here is what i've done by this guide: http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/adding-new-mass-action-to-admin-grid-in-magento/

The actions is appearing but when i select it and try to update the order statuss i get error for not exising link like this: http://mymagento.com/index.php/masscustomstatusses/controller/action/key/59418867a73fa5784acb31a23b2a1510/

I know i must add some more things but i have no idea what i should add.

Can you help me out so i can make this thing update the status ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You've done what you need to up to wiring in your controller.

First you need to declare a route for your controller(s) in the module config XML:

```
...
<admin>
    ...
    <routers>
        <masscustomstatusses>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>VivasIndustries_MassCustomStatusses</module>
                <frontName>masscustomstatusses</frontName>
            </args>
        </masscustomstatusses>
    </routers>
    ...
</admin>
...
```

Then build the controller:

```
<?php

class VivasIndustries_MassCustomStatusses_ControllerController
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{

    public function actionAction()
    {
        // Update status here
        // Can fetch selected items with $this->getRequest()->getParam()

        die('Looks like it works');
    }

}
```

I've used your naming convention exactly as you have described, though I doubt that's what you really want. Better to use standard Magento convention, with controller named `IndexController` and base action named `indexAction`. But you should get the idea.

---

Clear cache and try to run that mass action. The `die` statement should run, and fill in the blanks from there.

**NOTE**: I should point out that you're doing the same thing twice. You are both extending the sales order grid to add a mass action AND injecting it via event observer. As the article you reference points out, those are 2 *different* ways to do the same thing. You should choose one of those methods, only.

Comment: It seems i'm making something wrong, here is my config.xml after your answer: http://pastebin.com/caz87NMq and here is my /app/code/loca/VivasIndustries/MassCustomStatusses/controllers/IndexController.php: http://pastebin.com/89Q9dfQT And again when i try to update i got error 404 on http://mymagento.com/index.php/masscustomstatusses/controller/action/key/59418867a73fa5784acb31a23b2a1510/

Comment: The `admin/routers` setup should not be in the `global` node. Move it up a level, as a child of the root `config` node.

Comment: Now i got 404 but in the admin panel..

Comment: Please check the path to your controller, should be something like `app/code/local/VivasIndustries/MassCustomStatusses/controllers/ControllerController.php` -- note the lowercase `c` in the `controllers` directory.

Comment: Now i got 404 page redirect.any solution?

Comment: 404? Usually that means it redirected you to the frontend, which is a symptom of a misconfigured `<frontName>` on your module config XML, or an incorrect Magento route on your mass action definition. Also note that, when I wrote this answer, Magento did not have SUPEE-6788, which changed the way admin routes are configured. See this answer for more details: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/88815/1834 -- Most of what I wrote in 2014 is now deprecated and you should defer to the answer on this question.