# Trying to create an extension for new Custom Mass Status action update

Tags: php, 404

I am using Magento 1.9.1 .

I am working on a new extension which is adding new custom mass status action here:

[image]

Here is my code:

/app/code/local/VivasIndustries/MassCustomStatusses/etc/config.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <VivasIndustries_MassCustomStatusses>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </VivasIndustries_MassCustomStatusses>
  </modules>
  <admin>
    <routers>
        <masscustomstatusses>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>VivasIndustries_MassCustomStatusses</module>
                <frontName>masscustomstatusses</frontName>
            </args>
        </masscustomstatusses>
    </routers>
</admin>
<global>
    <blocks>
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <sales_order_grid>VivasIndustries_MassCustomStatusses_Block_Sales_Order_Grid</sales_order_grid>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
    </blocks> 
</global>
</config>
```

/app/code/local/VivasIndustries/MassCustomStatusses/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php:

```
<?php
class VivasIndustries_MassCustomStatusses_Block_Sales_Order_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid
{   
    protected function _prepareMassaction()
    {
        parent::_prepareMassaction();
         
        // Append new mass action option 
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem(
            'masscustomstatusses',
            array('label' => $this->__('New Mass 1'), 
                  'url'   => $this->getUrl('masscustomstatusses/controllers/NewMass') //this should be the url where there will be mass operation
            )
        );
    }
}
```

/app/code/local/VivasIndustries/MassCustomStatusses/controllers/IndexController.php:

```
<?php

class VivasIndustries_MassCustomStatusses_IndexController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{

    public function NewMassAction()
    {
        // Update status here
        // Can fetch selected items with $this->getRequest()->getParam()

        die('Looks like it works');
    }

}
```

So here is what i've done by this guide: http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/adding-new-mass-action-to-admin-grid-in-magento/

When i select `New Mass 1` and i click `Sumbit` i got error 404

[image]

I got this error on URL: http://mymagento.com/index.php/masscustomstatusses/controllers/NewMass/key/3ae4179b29ad706ef167e91bacf57c76/

Can you please help me fix this error?

NOTE: I've made this controller by instructions of this answer: [Adding new custom mass order status action](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45786/adding-new-custom-mass-order-status-action/45790#45790)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not your question but a rewrite of the block is not the best course of action here as a lot of other extensions might also want to add there own mass actions. A better approach in my view is to observe core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before and test if the block is Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Massaction

Comment: Have you logged off admin, and then logged in again enabling your extension? Magento returns 404 in new adminhtml pages until user logs in again.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
'url'   => $this->getUrl('masscustomstatusses/controllers/NewMass')
```

to

```
'url'   => $this->getUrl('masscustomstatusses/index/NewMass')
```

and also change the NewMassAction name to nameMassAction if it does not work.
Remember to flush cache and log in and out to test this.

Answer (score 1):

you took the wrong URL and got some naming issues.

Wrong Url:

`'url'   => $this->getUrl('masscustomstatusses/controllers/NewMass')`

magento calls controllers by structure of the requesting url.

Your Route is named `masscustomstatusses` yout controller is named `IndexController` and your Action is called `NewMassAction`. In Magento the URL is built up by three parts:

`module/controller/action` which will should, in your case, result in :
`masscustomstatusses/index/NewMass` so th egetUrl would look like:

```
$this->getUrl('masscustomstatusses/index/NewMass')
```

You should name your Action `newMassAction` instead of `NewMassAction` (and change the last parameter in the url of course) to avoid any naming issues.

Hope that helps.