# How to update admin routers of custom module for patch SUPEE-6788

Tags: adminhtml, routing, supee-6788, custom-admin-url, ce-1.9.2.2

I'm not sure how to update custom modules to work with the **SUPEE-6788** patch, [the instructions](https://info2.magento.com/rs/318-XBX-392/images/SUPEE-6788-Technical%20Details.pdf) are not very clear.

Based on Alan Storm's [tutorial](http://alanstorm.com/magento_admin_controllers), I created a simple module in the generator www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/ for testing. It has custom page in admin which works perfectly fine, but when I apply fixes required in SUPEE-6788, the admin page shows 404 error.

URL of the custom admin page is:

> localhost/index.php/admin/**admin_adminhello/adminhtml_adminhellobackend**/index/key/83f08ec4bddff37e47412e16acc8d3f6/

**Here's the config of the module:**

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Pulsestorm_Adminhello>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Pulsestorm_Adminhello>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <adminhello>
                <class>Pulsestorm_Adminhello_Helper</class>
            </adminhello>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
            <adminhello>
                <class>Pulsestorm_Adminhello_Block</class>
            </adminhello>
        </blocks>
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhello>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Pulsestorm_Adminhello</module>
                    <frontName>admin_adminhello</frontName>
                </args>
            </adminhello>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    ...
```

**Here's the controller:**

*/app/code/local/Pulsestorm/Adminhello/controllers/Adminhtml/AdminhellobackendController.php*

```
class Pulsestorm_Adminhello_Adminhtml_AdminhellobackendController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_title($this->__("My Test Page Title"));
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

### Solution

I replaced the `<routers>` part based on instructions from the patch like this (probably incorrectly):

```
<routers>
    <adminhtml>
        <args>
            <modules>
                <admin_adminhello after="Mage_Adminhtml">Pulsestorm_Adminhello_Adminhtml</admin_adminhello>
            </modules>
        </args>
    </adminhtml>
</routers>
```

But now the URL just shows `404 error`:

> localhost/index.php/admin/admin_adminhello/adminhtml_adminhellobackend/index/key/83f08ec4bddff37e47412e16acc8d3f6/

How to fix the module correctly for that new patch?
Do I just need to update `config.xml` or do I also need to change the admin page's URL after applying this patch?

Answer (score 44):

I managed to change my custom module to use the Magento new way as recommended with the patch 6788. So I give here as a reference for other, also answer the question in this thread.

1. Change to router in the config.xml file:

Before:

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhello>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Pulsestorm_Adminhello</module>
                <frontName>admin_adminhello</frontName>
            </args>
        </adminhello>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

After

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <adminhello before="Mage_Adminhtml">Pulsestorm_Adminhello_Adminhtml</adminhello>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

2. Change to the Controller

2.1.

Before Path

```
/app/code/local/Pulsestorm/Adminhello/controllers/Adminhtml/AdminhellobackendController.php
```

After path

```
/app/code/local/Pulsestorm/Adminhello/controllers/Adminhtml/Adminhello/AdminhellobackendController.php
```

2.2

Before class

```
class Pulsestorm_Adminhello_Adminhtml_AdminhellobackendController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action 
{
..
}
```

After class

```
class Pulsestorm_Adminhello_Adminhtml_Adminhello_AdminhellobackendController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
...
}
```

3. If you have an adminhtml.xml file (just give as an example as below)

Before

```
<config>
    <menu>
        <adminhello_config translate="title" module="adminhello">
            <title>Adminhello Settings</title>
            <sort_order>100</sort_order>
            <children>
                <list_action translate="title" module="adminhello">
                    <title>Manage Hellos</title>
                    <sort_order>4</sort_order>
                <action>adminhello/adminhtml_adminhellobackend</action>
                </list_action>
...
            </children>
        </adminhello_config>
    </menu>
</config>
```

After

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <adminhello_config translate="title" module="adminhello">
            <title>Adminhello Settings</title>
            <sort_order>100</sort_order>
            <children>
                <list_action translate="title" module="adminhello">
                    <title>Manage Hellos</title>
                    <sort_order>4</sort_order>
                <action>adminhtml/adminhello_adminhellobackend</action>
                </list_action>
...
            </children>
        </adminhello_config>
    </menu>
</config>
```

4. Change in your codes

Before: getting URLs

```
Mage::getUrl('adminhello/adminhtml_adminhellobackend/doSomething')
```

After: getting URLs

```
Mage::getUrl('adminhtml/adminhello_adminhellobackend/doSomething')
```

5. Change in layout files (if you have layout files, for example as below)

Before layout

```
<adminhello_adminhtml_adminhellobackend_index>
...
</adminhello_adminhtml_adminhellobackend_index>
```

After layout

```
<adminhtml_adminhello_adminhellobackend_index>
...
</adminhtml_adminhello_adminhellobackend_index>
```

Comment: Excellent! Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 17):

I lost hours figuring this out. Just because the Devs at Magento aren't capable of making an understandable configuration, or yet even documenting their code in a way a human being would be able to read it.

Let's have a look at the **config.xml** first

```
<routers>
<adminhtml>
    <args>
        <modules>
            <admin_adminhello after="Mage_Adminhtml">Pulsestorm_Adminhello_Adminhtml</admin_adminhello>
        </modules>
    </args>
</adminhtml>
```

The whole meaning of the Tags has changed. The Tag under "modules" is just a random name. you just need to make sure its unique to ensure it is not overwritten when the XML is compiled. It has influence on the URL.

```
<admin_adminhello after= ..... >
```

Magento now expects you to move your backend controller classes into a new subfolder called "adminhtml"
This is why in the config.xml you have to change the class name suffix by adding **_Adminhtml**.

```
... >Pulsestorm_Adminhello_Adminhtml</admin_adminhello> ....
```

In your case the folder would be located at

> app/code/local/Pulsestorm/Adminhello/controllers/Adminhtml

Now the real Problem. Using the other (better) system you had your own namespace defined by using the "FrontName" Tag. You don't have this luxury any more, so you need to make sure your controller has a unique name. Otherwise it would conflict with other Extensions.
So controllers named something like "AdminController.php" are no longer good, you have to make it something project specific, like in your case "**AdminhelloController.php**"

Your URL will then chagne to

> http://localhost/index.php/admin/adminhellobackend/index/key/83f08ec4bddff37e47412e16acc8d3f6/

Don't forget to adjust the controller classname after renaming or moving the file

> /app/code/local/Pulsestorm/Adminhello/controllers/Adminhtml/AdminhellobackendController.php

In this case the name would be  **Pulsestorm_Adminhello_Adminhtml_AdminhellobackendController**

Of course you must also adjust any URLs used in **menu items** and **forms** that you use in the backend

Also make sure you switch on **Developer Mode** in the **index.php** file. I noticed that if the controller has some bug in it, you also get a 404. With Develeport mode you get a Stacktrace error.

What I would also do, is just write a log once the controller is called, just so that you see if the controller method was accessed at all.

> /app/code/local/Pulsestorm/Adminhello/controllers/Adminhtml/AdminhellobackendController.php

```
class Pulsestorm_Adminhello_Adminhtml_AdminhellobackendController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        Mage::log('Controller was accessed', null, 'controller.log', true);
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_title($this->__("My Test Page Title"));
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you expand your answer if it works? thanks!

Comment: Ok, done... hope it helps

Comment: Heh, once caught a hilarious Magento developer  response back in the day on the old MagentoCommerce forums to your "_yet even documenting their code_" comment. "But the code is self documenting...". Umm didn't pass the perl pod test then, doesn't now. Thanks for the explanation above, I needed it.

Comment: *Magento now expects you to move your backend controller classes into a new subfolder called "adminhtml"* - this isn't true, the controller can be wherever you want it, it's only under the adminhtml folder in this case because you have defined a starting route of `Pulsestorm_Adminhello_Adminhtml` in config.xml.  You also need to update any admin layout handles, and calls to generates admin URL's like `getUrl()`.

Comment: @leedch I am pulling my hair out trying to figure out why this module will not work when I change the admin routing for SUPEE-6788 no matter what I try I get a 404 error. It's a simple module to print a custom html invoice. https://github.com/gaiterjones/magento-htmlinvoice

Comment: I do agree that it was a luxury to define custom `frontName`s for admin routes, and will surely miss it. Now we have to contend with greater likelihood of controller collision. Also, are there any performance benchmarks to compare the router's work to match on a unique `frontName` versus cycling through the `before`/`after` stack on `Mage_Adminhtml`? -- maybe this should be a meta post :)

Comment: @paj It is rather difficult to find your problem, as your GIT Repository is still showing the old setup. The instructions needed to change the admin routing are in the other posts here. The problem you're facing will probably be related to you not finding the new URL or having some tiny error in the XML, folder names, file names, class names or similar. If you want someone to look at it I suggest you make a GIT branch where you commit the changes for SUPEE-6788 and provide us a link to look at it.

Comment: @leedch I have updated the github with my latest version - I still can't get this to work despite many hours and multiple attempts. Perhaps you can spot the problem...https://github.com/gaiterjones/magento-htmlinvoice/

Comment: @paj
Got some things to try out.

1. According to your code your Url should be something like https://www.domain.com/admin/print/invoice/order_id/54
The Controller name should be changed. It is highly likely that the name PrintController could be used in some 3rd party extension. I don't think Magento usese that name, but I haven't checked.

2. The Controller Action just uses Echo. I understand Magento's system is too complicated. But a problem could be, that echo simply doesn't work in the controller try adding a Log entry, to see if the action actually gets fired

Comment: Mage::log('some text', null, 'invoice.log', true); If the Action is triggered, you'll get a file in /var/log/

Also I found an error in the XML. on the <htmlinvoice> node you forgot the last folder Name of the class, it should be

<htmlinvoice before="Mage_Adminhtml">PAJ_HTMLinvoice_Adminhtml_Htmlinvoice</htmlinvoice>

Comment: `Now the real Problem. Using the other (better) system you had your own namespace defined by using the "FrontName" Tag. You don't have this luxury any more`. This is not true. We can namespace our admin controllers through planned routing paths. My approach is to create menu actions as such: `<action>adminhtml/namespaceModule_index</action>` where `namespaceModule` matches the extension's namespace/module name. Then inside the `controllers/Adminhtml` directory create the directory "NamespaceModule" (matching actual values). Put controllers inside that directory and we now have namespaces.

Answer (score 8):

Here's an analysis/fix tool for extension and customization conflicts resulting from the Magento SUPEE-6788 patch.

https://github.com/rhoerr/supee-6788-toolbox

***Note:*** *Before applying any patch or patch fix, it is always recommended to make backup of your website and database.*

You can only analyze what need to fixed.

> **To analyze:** Run from SSH: `php -f fixSUPEE6788.php -- analyze`
>
> This will show which files have problems and how you can fix them. This will not apply the fix.

OR, you may apply the changes/fix as well.

> **To apply changes:** Run from SSH: `php -f fixSUPEE6788.php -- fix`
>
> This will analyze and apply the fix automatically.

Comment: Good Share +1 for u

Comment: Did this but still admin pages for all such modules are showing page 404