# Custom module redirected to home page

Tags: module, error, adminhtml, ce-1.9.0.1, media-images

`C:\xampp\htdocs\m1\app\etc\modules\Prasad_ImageSorter.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- 
/**
 * @category   Prasad
 * @package    Prasad_ImageSorter
 * @author     MaddyBoy

 */
 -->
<config>
    <modules>
        <Prasad_ImageSorter>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Prasad_ImageSorter>
    </modules>
</config>
```

`C:\xampp\htdocs\m1\app\code\local\Prasad\ImageSorter\etc\config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- 
/**
 * @category   Prasad
 * @package    Prasad_ImageSorter
 * @author     MaddyBoy

 */
 -->
<config>
    <modules>
        <Prasad_ImageSorter>
            <version>0.1.1</version>
        </Prasad_ImageSorter>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <imagesorter>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Prasad_ImageSorter</module>
                    <frontName>imagesorter</frontName>
                </args>
            </imagesorter>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <imagesorter>
                    <file>imagesorter.xml</file>
                </imagesorter>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <imagesorter>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Prasad_ImageSorter</module>
                    <frontName>imagesorter</frontName>
                </args>
            </imagesorter>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <imagesorter module="imagesorter">
                <title>ImageSorter</title>
                <sort_order>71</sort_order>               
                <children>
                    <items module="imagesorter">
                        <title>Manage Items</title>
                        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                        <action>imagesorter/adminhtml_imagesorter</action>
                    </items>
                </children>
            </imagesorter>
        </menu>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <all>
                    <title>Allow Everything</title>
                </all>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <Prasad_ImageSorter>
                            <title>ImageSorter Module</title>
                            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                        </Prasad_ImageSorter>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <imagesorter>
                    <file>imagesorter.xml</file>
                </imagesorter>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>   
    <global>
        <models>
            <imagesorter>
                <class>Prasad_ImageSorter_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>imagesorter_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </imagesorter>
            <imagesorter_mysql4>
                <class>Prasad_ImageSorter_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <imagesorter>
                        <table>imagesorter</table>
                    </imagesorter>
                </entities>
            </imagesorter_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <imagesorter_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Prasad_ImageSorter</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </imagesorter_setup>
            <imagesorter_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </imagesorter_write>
            <imagesorter_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </imagesorter_read>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <imagesorter>
                <class>Prasad_ImageSorter_Block</class>
            </imagesorter>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <imagesorter>
                <class>Prasad_ImageSorter_Helper</class>
            </imagesorter>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

Module is enabled

[image: enabled]

[image: admin_pannel]
when i click on Mange ITem it redirects to home page.

can one see what i am doing wrong.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Magento 1.9.2.2 or newer (SUPEE-6788) admin routers have to be added in anther way:

Change

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <imagesorter>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Prasad_ImageSorter</module>
                <frontName>imagesorter</frontName>
            </args>
        </imagesorter>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

To:

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Your_Alias before="Mage_Adminhtml">Prasad_ImageSorter_Adminhtml</Your_Alias>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

**Further information:**

- [Supee 6788 issue with config.xml](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92211/supee-6788-issue-with-config-xml)
- [How to update admin routers of custom module for patch SUPEE-6788](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/88045/how-to-update-admin-routers-of-custom-module-for-patch-supee-6788)

Comment: Ii created this module on my localhost having version 1.9.3 (working fine there) then i uploaded to client website having `Magento ver. 1.9.0.1`