# Get Url of the custom module is getting wrong

Tags: magento-1.9, url

i have a custom module called bookanappointment and its layout file is as follow with frontName as follows:-

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <bookanappointment>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Neo_Bookanappointment</module>
                <frontName>bookanappointment</frontName>
            </args>
        </bookanappointment>
    </routers>
</frontend>
<admin>
    <routers>
        <bookanappointment>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Neo_Bookanappointment</module>
                <frontName>admin_bookanappointment</frontName>
            </args>
        </bookanappointment>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

now i am trying to get the url of the indexController's list action.by using the following code

```
echo Mage::getUrl('bookanappointment/index/list');
```

i am getting url as follows

```
http://dev.ddecor.com/admin_bookanappointment/index/list/
```

which i dont want.

i need `http://dev.ddecor.com/bookanappointment/index/list/`

basically without admin_

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/88045/how-to-update-admin-routers-of-custom-module-for-patch-supee-6788

Defining the admin url like that is not viable with the latest magento security patches.

Comment: In which scope you are trying to get the URL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Luke said in the comment defining admin routes the way you do is not viable anymore. Please refer to this link to see how it must be done: [How to update admin routers of custom module for patch SUPEE-6788](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/88045/how-to-update-admin-routers-of-custom-module-for-patch-supee-6788)

However if you still want to keep using it you can replace

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <bookanappointment>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Neo_Bookanappointment</module>
                <frontName>admin_bookanappointment</frontName>
            </args>
        </bookanappointment>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

With

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <admin_bookanappointment>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Neo_Bookanappointment</module>
                <frontName>admin_bookanappointment</frontName>
            </args>
        </admin_bookanappointment>
    </routers>
</admin>
```