# Magento Plugin 404 - Admin

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, supee-6788, router

Hi guys recently updated Magento to the latest core and I am having an issue with a plugins page in the admin area. I am getting a 404 so I assumed it was an admin route issue.

I changed:

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <kiwiplugin>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Kiwicompany_Kiwiplugin</module>
                <frontName>kiwiplugin</frontName>
            </args>
        </kiwiplugin>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

to...

```
<admin>
    <routers>
      <kiwiplugin>
          <args>
              <modules>
                      <kiwiplugin before="Mage_Adminhtml">Kiwicompany_Kiwiplugin_Adminhtml</kiwiplugin>
              </modules>
          </args>
      </kiwiplugin>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

With no luck. I see a lot of conflicting information on whether to move controllers around etc, can someone talk me through my next steps? When I click the link in the nav in the admin I get:

http://www.example.com/index.php/kiwiplugin/adminhtml_kiwiplugin/index/key/....

Comment: Can you please add config.xml and adminhtml.xml?

Comment: Did you refresh the cache? And, why did you change the xml? rollback the xml refresh the cache see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to that XML change, you'd rename / move old controller files, and probably apply more code changes

Here you have an excellent explanation https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/88815/3566

And here you have a tool, which maybe can do all the job for you https://github.com/rhoerr/supee-6788-toolbox