# Help please , Well configured, but i can't get Model in Magento 1.9.4.5

Tags: magento-1.9, module, magento-1, grid, model

[image]

app/code/local/Info/news/Bock/Adminhtml/news/Grid.php

```
 <?php
    
    class Info_News_Block_Adminhtml_News_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid{
        public function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();
            $this->setId('newsGridView');
            $this->setDefaultSort('news_id');
            $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
            $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
        }
        protected function _prepareCollection(){
            //$collection=new Varien_Data_Collection();
           $collection = Mage::getModel('news/news')->getCollection();
            $this->setCollection($collection);
            return parent::_prepareCollection();
        }
    
    
        protected function _prepareColumns(){
            $this->addColumn("news_id",array(
                "header"=>Mage::helper("news")->__("ID"),
                "type"=>"number",
                "index"=>"news_id"
            ));
            $this->addColumn("news_title",array(
                "header"=>Mage::helper("news")->__("Title"),
                "type"=>"text",
                "index"=>"news_title"
            ));        $this->addColumn("news_content",array(
                "header"=>Mage::helper("news")->__("Content"),
                "type"=>"text",
                "index"=>"news_content"
            ));
        }
    }
```

app/code/local/Info/News/Model/News.php

```
<?php

class Info_News_Model_News extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract{
    protected function _construct() {
        $this->_init('news/news');
    }
}
```

app/code/local/Info/News/Model/Mysql4/News.php

```
<?php

class Info_News_Model_Mysql4_News extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract{
    protected function _construct() {
        $this->_init('news/news','news_id');
    }
}
```

app/code/local/Info/News/Model/Mysql4/News/Collection.php
<?php

```
class Info_News_Model_Mysql4_News_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract{
    public function _construct() {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('news/news');
    }
}
```

app/code/local/Info/News/Block/Adminhtml/News.php

```
<?php
class Info_News_Block_Adminhtml_News extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container {
    public function _construct (){
       
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_news';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'news';
        $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('news')->__("Manage News");
        parent::_construct();
    }
}
```

app/code/local/Info/News/etc/config.xml

```
  <config>
        <modules>
            <Info_News>
                <version>
                    0.0.1
                </version>
            </Info_News>
        </modules>
        <admin>
            <routers>
                <news>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                <module>Info_News</module>
                <frontName>admin_news</frontName>
                </args>
                </news>
            </routers>
        </admin>
        <adminhtml>
            <layout>
                <updates>
                    <news>
                        <file>info/news.xml</file>
                    </news>
                </updates>
            </layout>
        </adminhtml>
        <global>
            <models>
                <news>
                    <class>
                        Info_News_Model
                    </class>
                    <resourceModel>
                        news_mysql4
                    </resourceModel>
                </news>
                <news_mysql4>
                    <class>
                        Info_News_Model_Mysql4
                    </class>
                    <entities>
                        <news>
                            <table>
                                info_news
                            </table>
                        </news>
                    </entities>
                </news_mysql4>
            </models>
            <helpers>
                <news>
                    <class>
                        Info_News_Helper
                    </class>
                </news>
            </helpers>
            <blocks>
                <news>
                    <class>
                        Info_News_Block
                    </class>
                </news>
            </blocks>
            <resources>
                <news_setup>
                    <setup>
                        <module>
                            Info_News
                        </module>
                    </setup>
                    <connection>
                        <use>
                            core_setup
                        </use>
                    </connection>
                </news_setup>
                <news_write>
                    <connection>
                        <use>
                            core_write
                        </use>
                    </connection>
                </news_write>
                <news_read>
                    <connection>
                        <use>
                            core_read
                        </use>
                    </connection>
                </news_read>
            </resources>
        </global>
    </config>
```

app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/info/news.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.0.1">
    <news_adminhtml_news_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="news/adminhtml_news" name="news" />
        </reference>
    </news_adminhtml_news_index>
</layout>
```

**This is my result**

[image]

Comment: MySql4-classes are deprecated, better use Resource-classes

Comment: show me how ? please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `app/code/local/Info/News/Block/Adminhtml/News.php`, you should declare `__construct()` method (it contains 2 underscores) instead of `_construct()` method (it contain 1 underscore).

```
<?php
class Info_News_Block_Adminhtml_News extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container {
    public function __construct (){
       
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_news';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'news';
        $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('news')->__("Manage News");
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

**Updated: Found your issues:**

Your app/code/local/Info/News/etc/config.xml file has incorrect config. Xml nodes value for `version`, `models`, and `resources` must not contain any space nor new line.

And because `Mysql4` classes are deprecated, you should use `Resource` classes instead (It does not relate to your issue: can't get model).

**The implementation:**

**Step 1:** In `app/code/local/Info/News/etc/config.xml`:

1. Change `version` tag to `<version>0.0.1</version>`.
2. Change your code for `models` tag to the following:

```
<models>
    <news>
        <class>Info_News_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>news_resource</resourceModel>
    </news>
    <news_resource>
        <class>Info_News_Model_Resource</class>
        <entities>
            <news>
                <table>info_news</table>
            </news>
        </entities>
    </news_resource>
</models>
```

3. Change your code for `resource` to the following:

```
<resources>
    <news_setup>
        <setup>
            <module>Info_News</module>
        </setup>
    </news_setup>
    <news_write>
        <connection>
            <use>core_write</use>
        </connection>
    </news_write>
    <news_read>
        <connection>
            <use>core_read</use>
        </connection>
    </news_read>
</resources>
```

Finally, your `app/code/local/Info/News/etc/config.xml` should be changed like the following:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Info_News>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Info_News>
    </modules>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <news>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Info_News</module>
                    <frontName>admin_news</frontName>
                </args>
            </news>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <news>
                    <file>info/news.xml</file>
                </news>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
    <global>
        <models>
            <news>
                <class>Info_News_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>news_resource</resourceModel>
            </news>
            <news_resource>
                <class>Info_News_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <news>
                        <table>info_news</table>
                    </news>
                </entities>
            </news_resource>
        </models>
        <helpers>
            <news>
                <class>Info_News_Helper</class>
            </news>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
            <news>
                <class>Info_News_Block</class>
            </news>
        </blocks>
        <resources>
            <news_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Info_News</module>
                </setup>
            </news_setup>
            <news_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </news_write>
            <news_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </news_read>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

**Step 2:** Remove `app/code/local/Info/News/Model/Mysql4` folder.

**Step 3:** Create `app/code/local/Info/News/Model/Resource/News.php` file

```
<?php

class Info_News_Model_Resource_News extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
{
    protected function _construct() {
        $this->_init('news/news','news_id');
    }
}
```

**Step 4:** Create `app/code/local/Info/News/Model/Resource/News/Collection.php` file

```
<?php

class Info_News_Model_Resource_News_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract
{
    public function _construct() {
        $this->_init('news/news');
    }
}
```

Done, now you can go the admin to see result.

Comment: It doesn't work !!

Comment: Let's change `$this->setId('newsGridView');` to `$this->setId('newsGrid');` in app/code/local/Info/news/Bock/Adminhtml/News/Grid.php and update app/code/local/Info/News/Block/Adminhtml/News.php file as my updated answer and clear the cache.

Comment: And `<layout version="0.0.1">` should be changed to `<layout version="0.1.0">` in app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/info/news.xml

Comment: I did all your suggestions, but still not working
I can't progress since last Friday, please help

Comment: Let's zip your module and upload somewhere then send the link here, I'll check.

Comment: thanks Man :) https://easyupload.io/4rp98q

Comment: I'm waiting for you, i did all my tries but it doesn't work

Comment: I know, I probably can give you the solution at the end of today, not sure about that but I will help you resolve this issue. Now you can learn, and practice other features like creating a form, save form data in admin...

Comment: Thanks, man 
i don't know how to thank you for your quick interaction

Comment: @abderrahimrida I've fixed your issues, please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, finally, it works 
I use an xml formatter on my ide , which makes all this spaces and new lines, I try it with mysql4 , it works too

Comment: Why do you copy&paste my code?

Comment: Hi sv3n, it's misunderstood from your side. I've written all code by myself, not copying anything from yours.  I'll write more detail below.

Comment: As you know, the code declares `models` and `resources` are published and open source.... When I write my code, I usually refer to Magento code base (core). For example, we can take a look at `config.xml` from Mage_Cms from https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts/blob/1.9.4.x/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/etc/config.xml#L134

Comment: Second, what is the content you bring in your answer for the issue of the original poster? 1. You "think error come from router and/or layout file". 2 Tell the original poster to rename install script file name. 3. Change `action`'s value in adminhtml.xml file. 4 Modify block classes to use `_construct()` (one underscore). 5 Share 2 resource classes. 6. You tell him to change the layout xml file.

Comment: For your point 4, I told him to change that code 3 days ago which is before you advised him. For your point 2, the install script doesn't need to rename. 3, 6: he don't need to adjust because his router works as expected. For point 5, who knows  Magento 1 Resouce classes can give this advice, and my code is based on Magento core, not based on anyone. For point 1, the issue the original post had is incorrect value in `config.xml`, all other works as expected.

Comment: It's been a long time since I'm not working with Magento 1.x. I only work on Magento 2.x for years. I actually have been asked for help directly from @abderrahimrida 3 days ago (16th November, 2022). This is the first Magento 1's question I contribute to. After trying to help without running code but can't resolve the issue, I asked him for the module code for debugging purposes, then I have to install a Magento 1.9.4.5 install on my machine and then tried to debug. Finally, I end up with result that the config.xml has the problem.

Comment: @sv3n is everything clearly now?

Comment: Another thing I can see is you share the full content of config.xml while I indicate only `version`, `models` and `resources` node has the problem. I also didn't tell him to change the install script file name, news.xml layout content and adminhtml.xml content as you did. I've actually said strongly that "Mysql4 classes are deprecated, you should use Resource classes instead (It does not relate to your issue: can't get model)."

Comment: I agree, you finally help me unblocking my situation

Comment: check your mail please !

Comment: @abderrahimrida I've replied to your email.

Answer (score 1):

I think error comes from router and/or layout file.

config.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Info_News>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Info_News>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <news>
                <class>Info_News_Helper</class>
            </news>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
            <news>
                <class>Info_News_Block</class>
            </news>
        </blocks>
        <models>
            <news>
                <class>Info_News_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>news_resource</resourceModel>
            </news>
            <news_resource>
                <class>Info_News_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <news>
                        <table>info_news</table>
                    </news>
                </entities>
            </news_resource>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <news_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Info_News</module>
                </setup>
            </news_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
    <admin>
        <!-- fixed admin router -->
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <news before="Mage_Adminhtml">Info_News_Adminhtml</news>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <news>
                    <file>info/news.xml</file>
                </news>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

news.xml

```
    <adminhtml_news_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="news/adminhtml_news" name="news">
                <block type="news/adminhtml_news_grid" name="news.grid" as="grid"/>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_news_index>
```

- rename install script to `install-0.0.1.php`
- set path in adminhtml.xml to `<action>adminhtml/news/index</action>`
- in block classes use `_construct()` (one underscore)
- `class Info_News_Model_Resource_News extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract`
- `class Info_News_Model_Resource_News_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract`

Comment: Thanks, i've found the solution

Comment: @abderrahimrida you should also fix the router ...

Comment: @sv3n his router works fine, don't need to fix. I'll write more detail after answer you question in my answer.

Comment: The config router in the original poster will get URL: `base_url/admin/news/index` while the config router as your share is `base_url/adminhtml/news/index`

Comment: @TuVan admin routers changed with SUPEE-6788. Read https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/88045/how-to-update-admin-routers-of-custom-module-for-patch-supee-6788. It should be updated.

Comment: @sv3n I got it, thanks for the information.

Comment: @abderrahimrida you should update the router as sv3n advised to make your code safe. "Magento released Security Patch SUPEE 6788 on Oct 27, 2015, to ensure protection against threats such as remote code execution, information leaks, and cross-site scripting."

Answer (score 0):

[image]

look, when i check with this tool , the model has worked