# Add new mass action in order grid in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, pdf, massaction, packing-slip

[image]I am using Magento 1.9.1 .

I will create new mass action same like Print Packingslips in order grid also download pdf for same as Print Packingslips but some customization in pdf as per requirement.any one create any module or else knowing step so please share.

Answer (score 5):

Flow below steps

**Step:1**

Create file `Ar_Custom.xml` at location `app\etc\modules` and add below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Ar_Custom>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
        </Ar_Custom>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**Step:2** Create `Observer.php` at location `app\code\community\Ar\Custom\Model\`

```
<?php
class Ar_Custom_Model_Observer
{
    public function addMassAction($observer)
    {
        $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();
        $this->_block = $block;
        if (get_class($block) == 'Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Massaction' && $block->getRequest()->getControllerName() == 'sales_order') {
            $block->addItem('custom_action', array(
                'label' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Custom Action'),
                'url' => $block->getUrl('*/custom/masscustom'),
            ));
        }
    }
}
```

**Step:3** Create `CustomController.php` file at location `app\code\community\Ar\Custom\controllers\Adminhtml\CustomController.php` and below code

```
<?php
class Ar_Custom_Adminhtml_CustomController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{

    public function massCustomAction()
    {
        $orderIds = $this->getRequest()->getPost('order_ids', array());
        $this->_redirect('adminhtml/sales_order/');
    }
}
```

**Step:4** Create `config.xml` file at location `app\code\community\Ar\Custom\etc` and add below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Ar_Custom>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </Ar_Custom>
    </modules>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Ar_Custom after="Mage_Adminhtml">Ar_Custom_Adminhtml</Ar_Custom>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
     <adminhtml>
        <events>
            <core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
                <observers>
                    <newmodule_core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>Ar_Custom_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>addMassAction</method>
                    </newmodule_core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
                </observers>
            </core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>
    <global>
        <models>
            <custom>
                    <class>Ar_Custom_Model</class>
            </custom>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <custom_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </custom_write>
            <custom_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </custom_read>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

**Step:5** Flush and refresh all cache in admin end.

Comment: This one is not working i follow your step but not display.

Comment: have you clear cache?

Comment: yes but not working

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45786/adding-new-custom-mass-order-status-action using this i will create custom option but after this step what i don't know if you know then please tell me step.

Comment: my code working fine my end. can u please check module setup or not?

Comment: using your extension how to create custom option in order grid? i have attach image same custom option created so check and tell me.

Comment: you can see in my question, actually i have create this option using block but after that not redirect to my controllers so i need to help.

Comment: I used this, very nice! It works for "manage products" grid in my case, thanks!